# How to determine if a Windows patch is really needed?

Tags: windows

I’m performing an assessment on a Windows 2008 R2 SP1 machine using Nexpose. The scanner is stating that several patches are needed by the system, but in the past system admins have stated that the system is fully patched and up to date. What I’d like to do is manually determine if a patch is needed before letting the SA know, but I’m struggling to figure out if a patch is really needed. An example is with MS12-073 (Internet Information Services 7.5 KB2719033).

I’m working with 2 systems, one I manage (for testing) and the other is managed by another system administrator. Both are Windows 2008 R2 SP1 (x64-based). Nexpose reports that both systems need the patch (it checks the registry for a specific entry). I looked at the OVAL website for the vulnerability (http://oval.mitre.org/repository/data/item/show?id=oval%3aorg.mitre.oval%3adef%3a15959) and I’m confused on the “definition synopsis” section. First it has 2 sections for “check for vulnerable file version” but they are basically the same but with different versions. My patched system (that I managed and installed patch KB2719033) has version 7.5.7601.17514 of aspnetca.exe. According to oval.mitre.org my system is vulnerable. Am I reading it wrong?

I’ve also tried to verify via Microsoft website with the “file information” table (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2719033) but it lists several versions of the same file. I have sound a excel document that Microsoft publishes that lists patches and if they have been superseded, but this patch is not listed as being superseded by another patch (go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=245778)

My question is how do I read the “file information” table (from the Microsoft website) or the oval website to determine if systems are truly vulnerable or not? Or is there a better easier way to truly determine if a patch is needed (without using the windows update process which I don’t have access to).

*Edit*
I guess I'm looking for more of a framework to determine if a patch is needed. I have other examples that could be false positives (two others are MS11-013 and MS13-081). I tried using the file information from Microsoft and the OVAL process, but for KB2719033 those processes tell me that I'm still vulnerable, even though i have manually applied the patch on my test system.

Comment: Scan it using a security scanner that checks if that vulnerability really is accessible? </humor>

Comment: Microsoft's list has multiple architectures (x86, x64, etc) so that'd be why it shows up more than once.

Comment: They have 2 different tables, one for x86 and the other for x64 (at least in this case). In this example the table has this
Aspnetca.exe 7.5.7601.17855 229,376 01-Jun-2012 05:33 x64
On my patched system I have 7.5.7601.17514 which is older than what the patch supplies. So it's vulnerable?

Comment: That's what I did (using Nexpose) and it says the system is vulnerable because of a registry entry. I would like to verify that it is really needed before sending to the customer because in the past the Windows Update utility states that it is fully patched

Comment: Are your operational logs on? If they're not on, it isn't an issue from what I'm reading. Do you see the patch listed in your updates/patch list on the system in question (2716513)?

Comment: That KB is for the FTP vulnerability (server is not running FTP), but regardless no that patch nor the one i'm referring to (KB2719033) is not showing up as installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your system is still vulnerable ...probably because the patch didn't install correctly. Have them install the [patch manually](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35674) and check again.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not that simple. The processes and procedures in my organizations don't just allow them to download and reinstall.

Comment: @Keith Well, the real answer is that the patch has to be re-applied. Do whatever you have to do with the information given.

Comment: Ok, which i can do. But why do you say the system is still vulnerable? Because the Nexpose scanner discovered that the registry entry was missing and said the patch is needed? The patch could have been superseded by another patch (which it appears that it is not). I was hoping to get hard facts

Comment: @Keith You said in another answer that you can't find the patch as being installed on the system and also the file versions are earlier than the patch's. If it was superseded, then the versions would actually be *greater* than what the patch offers.

Comment: Rookie mistake…. The version that I gave in the other answer was for the patched system (7.5.7601.17514) which according to Microsoft and OVAL it is vulnerable. I guess I didn’t reboot because when I did the version changed to 7.5.7601.17855 (which is not vulnerable). Checking the file version on oval and Microsoft is the correct process.

Comment: In case anyone else is curious in the future the reason Microsoft lists multiple versions of the same file in the “file information” table is because of GDR and LDR. You would want to determine which one you are using (LDR or GDR) to get the correct file version. This link talks about GDR and LDR http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2011/11/30/how-does-windows-choose-which-version-of-a-file-to-install.aspx. So in my case I needed 7.5.7601.17855 because I have the GDR version.